# wmic shows different persistent flag for net use remote drive than it was actually created with

Tags: network-shares, wmic, net-use

I added some remote drives on my NAS to my laptops system by invoking:

```
net use \\someserver\ /user:any "anyKey" /PERSITENT:YES
```

To get access to these remote drives, as I didn't assign a letter for the drives, I created links and access them as regular Folders on my local drive

```
mklink /D localdrive\remotedrive\C \\someserver\c$
```

Sometimes some drives lose their "connection" while others don't. Windows simply can't resolve them anymore. So I created a skript that I run and with which I reconnect all drives.

This is really annoying so I started investigating. From:

```
wmic netuse get /value
```

I received the result:

```
AccessMask=1179785
Caption= ...
...
Name=\\someserver\
Persistent=FALSE
...
Status=OK
UserName=any
```

This kind of confirms my "suspicion" that those remote drives aren't added persistently. Any suggestions what I can do now?

Comment: Microsoft never makes anything easy. Check out this answer on Stack Exchange: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28093376/117259